# CSS class name bracket notation doesn't target inner CSS classes

Tags: css

I import the styles to the component like below. Up: It's a React component with a postcss-loader in Webpack.

```
import styles from './index.scss';
```

This is a gist from the component:

```
<div className={styles['container']}>
  <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='space-between'>
     <Col span={24}>
       ... ...
     </Col>
  </Row>
</div>
```

This is the styles:

```
    .container {
      margin-left: 24px;
      & .ant-row-flex.ant-row-flex-space-between.ant-row-flex-middle {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
          & .ant-col-24 {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
          }
      }
    }
```

Only the `.container`'s `margin-left: 24px;` gets displayed in the component.
How to get `.ant-row-flex.ant-row-flex-space-between.ant-row-flex-middle` from `Row` and `.ant-col-24` from `Col` to display too?

Comment: CSS does not have components, HTML does not parses attributes with `{{}}`. I think you are missing some information in question

Comment: it's seems to be a React code so add all the relevant tag. It's not only a CSS issue. using only the CSS tag isn't enough

Comment: I mean, are you working with a framework? Do you convert your `scss` files to `css`? You need to provide more information

Comment: It's a React component with a postcss-loader in Webpack.

Comment: Seems like postcss-loader didn't like nested names. I'll try to post more info later.